# Rendering small text with Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

A font rendering library (like say freetype) provides a function that will take an outline font file (like a .ttf) and a character code and produce a bitmap of the corresponding glyph in host memory.

For small text (like say up to 30x30 pixel glyphs) what's the most efficient way to render those glyphs to a Vulkan framebuffer?

Some options I've though about might be:

1. Render the glyphs with the font rendering library every time on demand, blit them with host code to a single host-side image holding a whole "text box", transfer the host-side image of the text box to a device local image, and then render a quad (like a normal image) using fragment shader / image sampler from the text box to be drawn.
2. At program startup cycle through all the glyphs host side, render them to glyph bitmaps.  Do the same as 1 but blit from the cached glyph bitmaps (takes about 1 MB host memory).
3. Cache the glyph bitmaps individually into device local images.  Rather than bitting host-side, render a quad for each glyph device-side and set the image sampler to the corresponding glyph each time.  (Not sure how the draw calls would work?  One draw call per glyph with a different combined image sampler every time?)
4. Cache all the glyph bitmaps into one large device-side image (layed out in a big grid say).  Use a single device-side combined image sampler, and push params to describe the subregion that contains the glyph image.  One draw call per glyph, updating push params each time.
5. Like 4 but use a single instanced draw call, and rather than push params use instance-varying input attributes.
6. Something else?

I mean like, how do common game engines like Unreal or Unity or Godot etc solve this problem?  Is there a typical approach or best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some considerations:

1. Rasterizing a glyph at around 30px with freetype might take [on the order of 10μs](https://medium.com/@raphlinus/inside-the-fastest-font-renderer-in-the-world-75ae5270c445). This is a very small one-time cost, but rendering e.g. 100 glyphs every frame would seriously eat into your frame budget (if we assume the math is as simple as 100 * 10μs == 1ms).
2. State changes (like descriptor updates) are relatively expensive. Changing the bound descriptor for each character you render has non-negligible cost. This could be limited by batching character draws (draw all the As, then the Bs, etc), but using push constants is typically the [fastest](http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/vulkan/2017/08/13/Vulkan-Uniform-Buffers.html).
3. Instanced drawing with small meshes (such as quads or single triangles) *can* be very slow on some GPUs, as they will not schedule multiple instances on a single wavefront/warp. If you're rendering a quad with 6 vertices, and a single execution unit can process 64 vertices, you may end up wasting 58/64 = 90.6% of available vertex shading capacity.

This suggests 4 is your best option (although 5 is likely comparable); you can further optimize that approach by caching the results of the draw calls. Imagine you have some menu text:

1. The first frame it is needed, render all the text to an intermediate image.
2. Each frame it is needed, make a single draw call textured with the intermediate image. (You could also blit the text if you don't need transparency.)

Comment: I'm going to try rendering all the glyphs to a big image at startup, and then making a single draw call, where the verticies are quads (6 verticies per glyph) with UV input attributes refering into that big image (ie just like a usual mesh / input texture draw).  It will be interesting to see the performance compared to host-side blitting.

Comment: I tried it with indexed calls, but it didn't work, I think because `gl_VertexIndex` doesn't enumerate the index buffer, it enumerates the vertex buffer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68946820/1131467  so I changed to instanced drawing and it seems to work now.  I wonder about the problem you mentioned in 3, if I will hit that on older graphics cards or something - any further info about the problem?  Do you which graphic card models have that problem?