# Per vertex ID rather than vertex index?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I'm trying to render a bunch of small axis-aligned (2d) quads in Vulkan, and rather than using a non-indexed draw call, I thought to try and minimize transfer overhead and use indexed draw with the following scheme:

```
#version 450
layout(location = 0) in vec2 inTopleft;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 inExtent;

vec2 positions[6] = vec2[](
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
);

void main() {
  vec2 position = positions[gl_VertexIndex % 6];

  gl_Position = vec4(inTopleft + position * inExtent, 0, 1);
}
```

That way I only need to send one vertex per quad, and then I just put the same vertex six times in the index buffer like:

```
index_buffer = [0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, ... n,n,n,n,n,n]
```

but this scheme doesn't seem to work because `gl_VertexIndex` I suspect is giving the value of the element in the index_buffer, right?  I mean for the first quad gl_VertexIndex is 0 for all six verticies, and then the second is 1 for all six verticies, and so on.  It's not actually giving 0,1,2,3,4,5 for the first quad, and 6,7,8,9,10,11 for the second quad, and so on.

Is that right?  And if so, is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using an instance draw call (non-indexed) with one instance per quad, and that seems to about double performance (200 fps -> 500fps, rendering about 10k quads), at least on my graphics card (`NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1)`).

What I mean is each quad has its own instance and so the draw call is called like `draw(nvertexes=6, ninstances=nquads)`, and so the shader can change from:

```
- vec2 position = positions[gl_VertexIndex % 6];
+ vec2 position = positions[gl_VertexIndex];
```

and of course the vertex buffer is now per instance instead of per vertex.

Comment: You cannot have indexID in vertex shader because of vertex cache: The vertices are only ever(theorethically) computed once, and then reused with indices. You could also try using point primitives, but they have size limitations, the size is given in pixels and they are culled by center... Or using geometry shader to multiply single vertex into 2 tris. I've read somewhere that GPUs have a fast path for this, but its probably a lie, needs testing. So most likely using instancing is best way.